# ADF application about are the Weblogic servers up or down. Servers are running on different machines

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf

Making an Oracle ADF application which should get data about is the Weblogic server running or not. Weblogic servers are installed on many different machines. So I need to get data about is the server running, how much OS RAM is available.. All the data will be populated to the ADF table.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you trying reimplement **oracle enterprise manager**.
If you need monitoring solution - use this one.
Otherwise its not an ADF question.

Comment: Alright, will check the possibilities of the enterprise manager!